# Xamarin Forms - How do I total space and available space on Android device?

Tags: android, forms, xamarin

I'm currently trying to upgrade our Xamarin Forms Android application to use the latest APIs.
However, since version 29, Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory has been deprecated.

e.g.

```
var usableSpace = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.UsableSpace;
var totalSpace = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.TotalSpace;
```

Some articles suggest using `requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` but this seems like sweeping the problem under the carpet for another day. I would rather fix the problem for the longer term.

I'm currently using the `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` to store app data.
In particular, the app downloads data from an API, so the app needs to be able to see if the device has enough space before an attempt is made.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `getExternalFilesDir()`, `getExternalCacheDir()`, or `getExternalMediaDirs()` (methods on Context) instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.  For more check: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory() .